# Using crypt() from crypt.h

Tags: c, pointers, cs50, crypt

I am doing the week2 pset for CS50.
When using the crypt function, the char pointers which point to the ciphertext of any string always point to the last thing I encrypted.
For example:

```
char password[] = "AAAA";
char toCrack[] = "AAzz";
printf("%s\n", password);
printf("%s\n", toCrack);

char *toCrackCiph = crypt(toCrack, "da");
char *passwordCiph = crypt(password, "aa");


printf("%s\n", passwordCiph);
printf("%s\n", toCrackCiph);
```

toCrackCiph and passwordCiph equal each other, even though their strings are not the same, and neither is the salt.

Am I making a simple pointer error somewhere?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I am not familiar with CS50.  I am answering this question under the assumption that `crypt` is the function [`crypt(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) from the traditional Unix standard C library.)

`crypt` is a very old function, from the days before anyone worried about thread-safety in C.  Every time you call it, it returns the *same pointer*, pointing to a static buffer inside the C library.  Each call overwrites the result of any previous call.

If you print out the result of the first `crypt` call before calling it again...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int 
main(void)
{
    char password[] = "AAAA";
    char toCrack[] = "AAzz";
    printf("%s\n", password);
    printf("%s\n", toCrack);

    char *toCrackCiph = crypt(toCrack, "da");
    printf("%s\n", toCrackCiph);

    char *passwordCiph = crypt(password, "aa");
    printf("%s\n", passwordCiph);
    return 0;
}
```

... then you will see two different strings.  The output on my computer is

```
AAAA
AAzz
daeBW5vt16USo
aaI8pRQwCn7N2
```

Since you are using salt strings that request the old DES-based password hash algorithm, you should get the same thing.

This is a classroom exercise, but I must still point out that the old DES-based password hash can be broken by brute force on any modern computer, so it should never be used for real passwords.  You can probably get a better algorithm to be used by specifying a different style of salt string, something like `"$5$bpKU3bUSQLwX87z/$"`.

Comment: "old DES-based password hash can be broken by brute force" --- that's exactly what the Problem Set is about. Cracking the Hash by brute force 

Comment: So how do I compare two outputs from `crypt` function call?

Comment: @abhisekp You have to copy the string that `crypt` returns into another buffer before calling `crypt` again.

Comment: I did this to copy the hash to another string (_and not to the static hash location_) `char new_hash[14]; strcpy(new_hash, crypt(new_password, salt));`